# int to enum: cast works fine, assignment fails

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, graphics, enums

I am trying to set a property that is an enum using an integer value, like

```
Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();
int enumValue = 2; // corresponds to SmoothingMode.HighQuality
g.SmoothingMode = (SmoothingMode)2; // does not have expected result
// also tried:
SmoothingMode sm = (SmoothingMode)Enum.ToObject(typeof(SmoothingMode), enumValue); // works correctly
g.SmoothingMode = sm; // still doesn't work!
```

But the object's property never gets set to the correct enum value. I've run this through VS2010's debugger and the casting and/or use of Enum.ToObject works correctly, but after the assignment, `g.SmoothingMode` is *AntiAlias* instead of HighQuality, for example. In fact, no matter what number I cast, the assignment always results in either AntiAlias (int equivalent 3) or None (int equivalent 4) being assigned to the object's property.

Is there something different about when an enum is a property of a class that affects casting & assignment, or just something weird about Graphics.SmoothingMode, or what?

Comment: OK so everyone has pointed out that most of the SmoothingMode enum values are functionally equivalent. No explanation as to why it doesn't leave well enough alone and allow a value assignment to stand as-is, however. So, _my_ theory is that this seemingly enforced equivalence is implemented inside the `Grahpics` property's `get` method...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [SmoothingMode Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28SYSTEM.DRAWING.DRAWING2D.SMOOTHINGMODE%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK,VERSION=V4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true) description.

Quote:

> Default , None, and HighSpeed are
>   equivalent and specify rendering
>   without smoothing applied.
>
> AntiAlias and HighQuality are
>   equivalent and specify rendering with
>   smoothing applied.

So basically there are three modes:

- antialiased rendering (`HighQuality`, `AntiAlias`)
- no antialiasing (`Default`, `None`, `HighSpeed`
- invalid (`Invalid`)

There is no problem with the enumeration in your code. The following line is legit.

```
g.SmoothingMode = (SmoothingMode)2;
```

It just internally treats `HighQuality` the same way as it does `AntiAlias`.

If you do:

```
g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
var x = g.SmoothingMode;
```

`x` will return `SmoothingMode.AntiAlias` as this basically the same.

Answer (score 4):

HighQuality and AntiAlias are equivalent per the spec, however how .Net is accomplishing this seems to be rather funky.

I ran System.Drawing.Graphics through reflector and found some interesting magic going on, with variants of the following in the getter and setter:

```
int status = SafeNativeMethods.Gdip.GdipGetSmoothingMode(new HandleRef(this, this.NativeGraphics), out smoothingMode);
// ...
return smoothingMode;
```

This appears to be a call to some old Win32 API located in GdiPlus.dll where the data seems to be coming back potentially different than entered.

MSDN Link to GDI GetSmoothingMode:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535723(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: -1 - Not sure I understand why this is upvoted. This is wrong explanation. This is how this enum is defined: `public enum SmoothingMode
{
    AntiAlias = 4,
    Default = 0,
    HighQuality = 2,
    HighSpeed = 1,
    Invalid = -1,
    None = 3
}`

Comment: would you agree that your answer is not relevant to the question?

Comment: Yeah, I had already ran a little code that gave me the actual int equivalents of all SmoothingMode values and Alex Aza is correct.

Comment: My appologies, you are both right, I ran into a problem with an enum recently with the exact same behavior and wildly different causes, my bad for not doing more due diligence before answering.  Updating answer with more relevant information after doing some digging.

Answer (score 2):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z714w2y9.aspx):

> Default, None, and HighSpeed are
>   equivalent and specify rendering
>   without smoothing applied. AntiAlias
>   and HighQuality are equivalent and
>   specify rendering with smoothing
>   applied.

So when setting the SmoothingMode property to either Default, None or HighSpeed is equivalent to setting it to None. AntiAlias and HighQuality is the equivalent to setting it to AntiAlias.

Apparently you can only set Graphics.SmoothingMode to one of two possible values: None or AntiAlias.

Answer (score 0):

Ah.. Ok.. I don't think you actually have a problem.

From their specifications [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z714w2y9.aspx), they state that "AntiAlias and HighQuality are equivalent and specify rendering with smoothing applied."

Internally I think it only maintains the "none" or "anti-aliased" values.

Answer (score 0):

See the documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z714w2y9.aspx). It says "AntiAlias and HighQuality are equivalent and specify rendering with smoothing applied." I'm assuming that the enum is coded such that enum SmoothingMode { AntiAliased = 2, HighQuality = 2 }. When the cast is performed, the first item declared in the enum with value 2 will be selected. In this case AntiAliased appears first so it is selected. This would not be a problem if instead you set the SmoothingMode property from an enum value instead.